# Steam DISK WRITE ERROR, nothing else reports errors

Tags: hard-drive, installation, hardware-failure, steam

I am encountering an extremely odd error with Steam.

When trying to install the game Strike Suit Zero: Director's Cut it reports a DISK WRITE ERROR 1.1 GB in, which is odd because NOTHING else will cause that error to occur.

HWiNFO also reports no errors.

I am using Windows 10.

Edit: I am now on a CONTENT FILE LOCKED error, stuff is downloaded.

Comment: Might be worth doing a surface scan using one of the popular tools, just to make sure it's not a bad disk... https://www.minitool.com/help-pw/disk-test-surface.html

Comment: Does the disk have enough free space? What exactly is the error? Where do you have it installed and where do you want to install the game?

Comment: @Mokubai turns out it was Steam BS causing it to happen. I got it installed and now I have encountered a CONTENT FILE LOCKED error, no permission errors should be occurring, I checked everything. It doesn't output an error, just CONTENT FILE LOCKED.

Comment: @Seth I do have enough space, it is CONTENT FILE LOCKED, I want it in my D: drive, and it is in the D: drive

Comment: Might be that you need to do a reboot to get Steam to shutdown properly and whatever has the file locked to release it. Not a shutdown and restart, actually reboot.

Comment: Will try, be back eventually, I need sleep so I will respond in 12hr

Comment: @Mokubai Steam still won't install the game.

Comment: UPDATE: There is a folder system in the game folder, but no files. Should I clear that out?

Comment: Steam has a built in way to check the files. Right click the game in your game list and select properties. In the window that opens go to the "Local files" tab. There should be a "verify files" button which should check all the files and re-download corrupt files. https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

Answer (score -1):

Here are ten methods we can try to fix "Steam Disk Write Error":

Method 1. Modify Steam Settings to Fix the Error
Method 2. Change your Folder Security
Method 3. Reset Steam Configuration on your PC
Method 4. Check out the Missing and Corrupted Files
Method 5. Check Anti- Virus Software
Method 6. Directory Permissions
Method 7. Check your Hard Drive
Method 8. Check Fire wall settings
Method 9. Exclude steam from DEP
Method 10. Verification of Game Cache Files

We can refer the details in this article:
https://validedge.com/steam-disk-write-error/